# Capybara: после создания объекта, не происходит перенаправление на action show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

```
e 'rails_helper'

feature 'add lost pet' do
  given(:data) {attributes_for(:lost_pet)}

  scenario 'add new lost pet with valid data' do
    visit  root_path
    click_on 'Register new lost pet'  
      fill_in 'Name', with: data[:name]
      fill_in 'Type', with: data[:type]
      fill_in 'Breed', with: data[:breed]
      fill_in 'Gender', with: data[:gender]
      fill_in 'Size', with: data[:size]
      fill_in 'Colour', with: data[:colour]
      fill_in 'Age', with: data[:age]
      fill_in 'Age unit', with: data[:age_unit]
      fill_in 'Description', with: data[:description]
      fill_in 'Collar description', with: data[:collar_description]
      check 'Desexed', :checked
      check 'Microchipped', :checked
      fill_in 'Microchip number', with: data[:microchipped_number]
      select '2015', from: "lost_pet[date_missing(1i)]"
      select 'October', from: 'lost_pet[date_missing(2i)]'
      select '10', from: 'lost_pet[date_missing(3i)]'
      fill_in 'Rewald', with: data[:rewald]
      fill_in 'Image', with: data[:image]
      fill_in 'Adress lost', with: data[:adress_lost]
      click_on 'Create'

      lost_pet = LostPet.last

      expect(current_path).to eq lost_pet_path(lost_pet)
      expect(page).to have_content('Oskar')
  end
end
```

** контроллер: **

```
class LostPetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_lost_pet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
      @lost_pets = LostPet.all
  end

  def new
    respond_with(@lost_pet = LostPet.new)
  end

  def create
    respond_with(@lost_pet = LostPet.create(lost_pet_params))
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@lost_pet)
  end

  def edit
    @lost_pet
  end

  def update
    @lost_pet.update(lost_pet_params)
    respond_with(@lost_pet)
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with(@lost_pet.destroy)
  end

  private

  def load_lost_pet
    @lost_pet = LostPet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def lost_pet_params
    params.require(:lost_pet).permit([:id, :name, :type_pet, :breed, :gender, :size,
      :colour, :age, :age_unit, :description, :collar_description, :desexed, 
      :microchipped, :microchip_number, :date_missing, :rewald, :image, :adress_lost,
      :name_host, :telephone, :email])
  end
end
```

Перехожу в метод new, создаю новый объект, далее после сохранения происходит редирект на метод show. Запускаю, создаю новый объект, меня перекидывает в show. Все работает. Но! Почему то в самом тесте, после click_on 'Create'LostPet.last равен nill

А также проверка expect(page).to have_content('Oskar') выдает след ошибку:

** add lost pet add new lost pet with valid data
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Oskar')
       expected to find text "Oskar" in "Register new lost pet Name Breed Type Gender Size Colour Age Age unit Description Collar description Desexed Microchipped Microchip number Date missing 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 January February March April May June July August September October November December 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 Rewald Image Adress lost Name host Telephone Email"
     # ./spec/acceptance/lost_pet/create_spec.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in ' **

Получается в тесте не происходит редиректа в action show. Как решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в rails_helper (найдите в файле строку и измените в ней или в spec_helper)

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

на

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Это потому что когда вы создаете запись она записывается в память а не в базу (Существует виртуально скажем так, не персистентная)
Установите гем Database-Cleaner

```
gem 'database_cleaner', group :test
```

Чтоб данные всегда по окончанию тестов из неё удалялись нужен этот гем. Если этого не делать могут произойти коллизии с данными в тестовой базе (остаточные записи в базе с предыдущих тестов могут к примеру).
Опять же, в rails_helper перед окончанием блока *RSpec.configure do |config|* пропишите следующий код :

```
# Настройки для удаления данных из базы данных после тестирования
  config.before(:suite) do # выполняеться этот код перед запуском всего файла со спеками
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation) #удаляются все данные при помощи стратегии truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do # перед каждым тестом сохраняем данные в положении ТРАНЗАКЦИИ, когда данные реально НЕ ЗАПИСЫВАЮТЬСЯ в базу.
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js:true) do # для каждой спеки помеченной JS-TRUE, используем стратегию truncation. Которая создаёт данные в таблице для теста и очишает её по окончанию
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do # в начале каждого теста устанавливаем чистильшик базы для отслеживания изменений в базе
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do # ну и после каждого теста чистильшик подчишает базу
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Этот код,будет работать как описано. в комментариях.